# How to retrieve dynamically created html element data with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, dynamic, web

I am new to JQuery and web development. I am developing a dynamic web application. I am using html and JQuery on front-end, communicating with server side via servlets. I create many question pages where questions retrieved from database and inserted into a single html file. So each page contains one question which is dynamically created. I need to get the answers selected from the input elements which could be radio, checkbox, text, slider. The problem is, I want the answers in the same order of questions. I am planning to store them in a var separating with ";" and pass it to server-side via servlet and then store. How can I get selected values with JQuery when next button is clicked?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Here is a sample generated question code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="question1">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
<div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <legend>Gender:</legend>
                <input type="radio" name="singleSelection" id="choice1">
                <label for="choice1">Male</label>
                <input type="radio" name="singleSelection" id="choice2">
                <label for="choice2">Female</label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="button" value="Next" data-theme="b"></div>
        </fieldset>
        </div>  
    </div>
   </div>

<div data-role="page" id="question2">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
<div data-role="content">
     <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend>What are your hobbies?</legend>  
        <input type="checkbox" name="multiSelection0" id="multiSelection0"> 
        <label for="multiSelection0">Cinema</label>  
        <input type="checkbox" name="multiSelection1" id="multiSelection1"> 
        <label for="multiSelection1">Football</label>  
        <input type="checkbox" name="multiSelection2" id="multiSelection2">
        <label for="multiSelection2">Basketball</label>  
     </fieldset> 
     <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
           <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="button" value="Next" data-theme="b"></div>
     </fieldset></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".ui-block-a input").click(function() {
   var results = new Array();
   var contents = $(this).parents("div").parents("div").find("input");
    contents.filter(":checked").each(function() {
        var idx = $(this).index();
       results.push($(this).parent().children().get(idx+1).innerHTML);
    });
    contents.filter(":text").each(function() {
        results.push($(this).val());
    });

    alert(results.join(";"));
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M6meQ/)

This will alert the values concatenated with a semicolon; you can then pass that on to whatever you need. This is making some assumptions about the structure of the HTML for text-input questions. And for sliders, are you using HTML5 or jQuery UI, or something else?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using JQuery mobile. When I used the function you provided this is what alerted in the screen: 

<span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Male</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-radio-on ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span>

Comment: [JSFiddle Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/HZK2d/19/) I could retrieved id attr with your function but it works when html page involves the code itself. But for the inserted html code even click function didnt fired.
$.get('TestServlet',{parameter:parameter1},function(responseText) { 
                   $(responseText).insertAfter('#page3');
                });
I insert the generated html code with get as seen above and when I clicked the Next button in the generated questions come with insertAfter, click event not fired. Any idea what could be reason?

Comment: When `$(".ui-block-a input").click...` is called, it places the event on all the buttons currently in the DOM. If they're added later, you need to call the function after they're added.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As you mentioned calling the function after DOM elements created solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The code bellow will post data=1 and info=2 to your_generator.php script and the response, that should be a valid HTML, will be placed inside a div called `localdiv`.

In your_generator.php you can access data and info by `$_POST['data']` and `$_POST['info']`. Yes, this is only an example for PHP, you can use any other server side script and you can use as many parameters you want/need. The server side script should check these parameters and generate the piece of HTML you what and then *echo* it out.

```
$.post("your_generator.php", {data:1, info:2}, function(data, s) {
     $('#localdiv').html(data);
}, "html");
```

**EDIT**

To send data back to server simply change your generated HTML to wrap it with an ordinary form, like:

```
<form action="my_script.php" method="post">
<!-- lots of html and inputs -->
</form>
```

When you put this inside any local container the form will behave like any other and will submit data to your server script.

Comment: I can create html data and insert it into the html file. But my question is to retrieve the selections from that generated fields.

Comment: Ok, so simply wrap your generated HTML into a form with its action pointing to your server script like any other form.